# Which files are safe to delete?

Tags: disk-usage, aws, snapshot, ncdu

so I used `ncdu` to help free up some storage and for the following log:

```
--- / ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3.1 GiB [##########] /usr                                                                                                                                                                         
2.0 GiB [######    ] /snap
1.8 GiB [######    ] /home
1.2 GiB [###       ] /var
432.9 MiB [#         ] /opt
182.6 MiB [          ] /boot
28.5 MiB [          ] /root
7.1 MiB [          ] /etc
4.2 MiB [          ] /tmp
920.0 KiB [          ] /run
172.0 KiB [          ]  PDF
e  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
8.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /media
4.0 KiB [          ]  port8051-redirect.conf
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
 0.0   B [          ] /sys
 0.0   B [          ] /dev
 @   0.0   B [          ]  libx32
  @   0.0   B [          ]  lib64
 @   0.0   B [          ]  lib32
 @   0.0   B [          ]  sbin
 @   0.0   B [          ]  lib
 @   0.0   B [          ]  bin
```

However I'm not sure which files are safe to delete and most importantly how to delete them. Any input shall be appreciated.

Comment: How much space do you want to save? What do you use the machine for? You have an `aws` tag, is this a virtual machine? The normal way to delete things from places such as /usr is to remove `packages`.  For example if you don't need to use the `openoffice` set of tools then you could remove them. Having said that, 10Gbytes is not an unreasonable size for a balanced linux install. The space in /snap is the first place I would look to see if there are optional things that you don't need.

Comment: I would say that in /var/log almost everything can be cleaned up except directories, and for /snap check this in Super User : https://superuser.com/a/1330590 (be careful as normally snap packages should be in /var/lib/snapd). Additionally if on Amazon Linux perhaps yum clean all will cleanup /var/lib/yum/repos.

Comment: Welcome to the community. You should [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738986/edit) your question to add a bit context, for example your operating system version, what you use the system for... please see the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for advice [how to formulate a good question[(https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Determining what's "safe" to delete is practically impossible without knowing what you use the system for. Also, how is tag `aws` related to the issue? Please don't answer in comments, but indeed edit the question instead.

Comment: Anything that's in `/usr/` that isn't in `/usr/local/` was almost certainly put there by your distro's package management system and trying to remove stuff from there without using your package manager to do so *will lead to complications down the line that you lack the skills to handle well*. **Don't**.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the output, your problem isn't what you think it is and you're almost certainly going about it the wrong way.

As per my comment, anything that's under `/usr/` but not under `/usr/local/` was most likely put there by the package manager of whatever distribution you're using, almost certainly at your explicit or implicit request when you told it to install software (which will include its dependencies).

If you want to clear up space there -- which you'll have to, as it's currently full -- the proper way to do so will be to use your distro's package manager, whichever tool that may be, to see what software you've installed that you don't need, and then uninstall that.

A word to the wise: **Err on the side of caution** -- judging by the questions you're asking, you still have a great deal to learn about what you may or may not need. Read the description of anything you're unsure about carefully, and leave anything starting with `lib` strictly alone. It's almost certainly a library for something else you're using, and removing it will cause whatever uses it to also be removed.

I have no easy answers for you here, because you didn't ask a terribly specific question -- I can't tell you what package manager to use because you didn't say what distribution you're using; I can't tell you what you may or may not need because you've said nothing at all about your use case for the system. Good luck.